# libxml2 HTML parsing problems

Tags: html, c, html-parsing, libxml2

I'm using libxml2 to parse HTML:

```
static htmlSAXHandler simpleSAXHandlerStruct = {
    NULL,                       /* internalSubset */
    NULL,                       /* isStandalone   */
    NULL,                       /* hasInternalSubset */
    NULL,                       /* hasExternalSubset */
    NULL,                       /* resolveEntity */
    NULL,                       /* getEntity */
    NULL,                       /* entityDecl */
    NULL,                       /* notationDecl */
    NULL,                       /* attributeDecl */
    NULL,                       /* elementDecl */
    NULL,                       /* unparsedEntityDecl */
    NULL,                       /* setDocumentLocator */
    NULL,                       /* startDocument */
    NULL,                       /* endDocument */
    NULL,                       /* startElement*/
    NULL,                       /* endElement */
    NULL,                       /* reference */
    charactersFoundSAX,         /* characters */
    NULL,                       /* ignorableWhitespace */
    NULL,                       /* processingInstruction */
    NULL,                       /* comment */
    NULL,                       /* warning */
    errorEncounteredSAX,        /* error */
    NULL,                       /* fatalError //: unused error() get all the errors */
    NULL,                       /* getParameterEntity */
    NULL,                       /* cdataBlock */
    NULL,                       /* externalSubset */
    XML_SAX2_MAGIC,             //
    NULL,
    startElementSAXP,           /* startElementNs */
    endElementSAXP,             /* endElementNs */
    NULL,                       /* serror */
};
```

The `charactersFoundSAX` and `errorEncounteredSAX` functions do get called, but the `startElementSAXP` and `endElementSAXP` functions never get called.

If I change the parsing from HTML and parse XML instead (and change all the definitions including 'html' to 'xml', e.g. into `xmlSAXHandler`), the functions do get called correctly.

Why is that?

Comment: What do you mean by: If I change the parsing from HTML and parse XML instead?  Care to give us the HTML/XML files so we can actually start digging into it?  All I can say is that my HTML SAX parser works.

Comment: You can try `http://www.google.com/index.html`. Are you sure these two functions get called in your parser:

http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#startElementNsSAX2Func
http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#endElementNsSAX2Func

Comment: Well no, I don't use the NS-aware function slots in html mode.
That will be your problem, I reckon, HTML has no notion of name spaces, maybe you're better off using the startElement/endElement slots?

Comment: Yes, these are the ones I'm currently using. Is there any easy way to determine inside the `endElement` slot function where the corresponding start element was opened (e.g. if I want to extract a `div` from the HTML that has nested divs inside it)?

Comment: Huh? That's the beauty about sax, it's all your responsibility, in the worst-case keep a tree of visited nodes, you know sax traverses the tree depth-first so it's easy to build up that tree.

Comment: Naw, SAX isn't beautiful when you're dealing with HTML where the data can be pretty much anywhere inside the file, and it's not easily determinable which data you need and which data you don't need. I guess DOM would be much easier, I'm just using SAX because it's faster and uses less memory...

Comment: Well, it depends :) This has gone quite subjective now but I feel free when using sax: I can use my own memory management, I can keep track of just the stuff I need, I can exit prematurely (DOM always builds the tree before I can have fiddle), etc. etc.
Not really your original question though.  I think I post my observation as an answer so you can close this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML is not namespace aware and hence using just the `startElementNs`/`endElementNs` function slots in a SAX parser will result in your observed behaviour.

Simple fix: Fill in the `startElement`/`endElement` slots.

You can easily use wrappers to match the different signature and then call just the one underlying function in both XML and HTML mode.